# *.proto files are ignored

Tags: protocol-buffers, scalapb

Im trying to use protobuffers and scalaPB, i've added:

```
import com.trueaccord.scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.trueaccord.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % 
scalapbVersion % "protobuf"

PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
  scalapb.gen() -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value
)
```

and below lines to plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "0.99.3")

libraryDependencies += "com.trueaccord.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.5.47"
```

and .proto file under src/main/protobuf:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "scalapb/scalapb.proto";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

package actors;
message ExamplePROTO {
    double value = 1;
}
```

but using sbt compile nothing happens - class is not generated in target. File is ignored, because even with some typo in protobuf file project still compiles. Ive also tried to look at debug logs using

```
logLevel in Global := Level.Debug
```

but the only files .proto which are mentioned there are some internal ones like: /target/protobuf_external/google/protobuf/source_context.proto

How can I proceed with it? Can I get some more information what scalaPB is looking at?

Comment: Looks like you're doing everything right. Can you try cloning this test project and see if it compiles for you https://github.com/thesamet/scalapb-test? If it does - then let's find out how it's different from your project. If it doesn't compile - I suspect it's a system/environment issue (like something interfering with ScalaPB from ~/.sbt)

Comment: thx, at least I know that I dont do something very against existing practice ; )  I have a mix of play / akka there, I will try to clone your repo and cut some dependencies to track it

Comment: Your repo compiles, classes are generated. Maybe its my different project structure? Play keep its classes in 'app' directory not 'src'. Ive created '/src/main/protobuf' dir just for .proto file, maybe I need to point it somehow in  scalaPB configuration?

Comment: ok, Ive found your answer: https://github.com/scalapb/ScalaPB/issues/234 seems that Play breaks some paths of scalaPB. Ive typed 'protocSources' in sbt, and its suprisingly pointing to '/app/protobuf' so Ive moved my .proto file there. Now its trying to compile it! :) but complains: scalapb/scalapb.proto: File not found.
google/protobuf/wrappers.proto: File not found.

Comment: it works! In the morning Ive changed versions to those which you use in your scalapb-test ( "scalapb-runtime-grpc" % "0.5.43" ) but had errors like those from above comment. I rolled it back to those mentioned in my post and its ok now. Can you tell me what caused a change of path to /app/protobuf for scalaPB? Is it normal thing that mixing in playframework can break scalaPB defaults?